# Is it possible to pass an object in a WCF using Entity Framework?

Tags: .net, wcf, entity-framework

Is it possible to pass an object in a WCF using Entity Framework?

Comment: Your question is a bit incomplete here; can you pass an object in a WCF [what]?

Comment: -1 You can pass objects in WCF. Entity Framework has to do with persistence.  Are you looking for a tutorial on how to use EF to retrieve data from a database and return the result using a WCF service? If so, let us know.

Answer (score 1):

WCF data services may be what you are looking for, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/odata.aspx

Answer (score 0):

There as an example [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/entitybag/) that uses Entity Framework objects over WCF.  As noted in comments, it's hard to tell if this is exactly what you need without more detail.

> Perseus is a small project designed to
>   explore ways for exchanging graphs of
>   Entity Framework entities over WCF web
>   services.